# Newly inserted Contact Not returned in first people:searchContacts

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

We are trying to migrate from Google Contacts API to Google People API due to deprecation.

Some weird behaviour following the creation of a Contact with the Google People API.

firstly we create a new contact

```
POST https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:createContact?sources=READ_SOURCE_TYPE_CONTACT&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "names": [
    {
      "givenName": "Test",
      "familyName": "Contact"
    }
  ],
  "emailAddresses": [
    {
      "value": "test@tester.com.au"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then we query the newly created contact

```
GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:searchContacts?query=test%40tester.com.au&readMask=names%2CemailAddresses%2Cmetadata%2Cmemberships%2CuserDefined&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```

The search returns empty result

```
{}
```

If we now query again we get the expected result

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "person": {
        "resourceName": "people/c1041359888227912421",
        "etag": "%EggBAj0JPhY3LhoBAiIMd0UrSkMrM21tMG89",
        .....
  ]
}
```

Not sure what is going on here?  Anybody else experiencing this strange behaviour??

Comment: This sounds a bit like a propagation issue. It will take a while for a newly inserted record to be available with a GET request. Though in theory you should get a 4XX error for "contact not found" or something like that - how long are you waiting between INSERT and GET?

Comment: Nevermind, I tested this and its true even after waiting a couple of hours.

Comment: @iansedano indeed, its not a propagation issue - only workaround is to query after insert. Although I do recall seeing multiple queries before the correct result was returned.  Is a major problem as we use the email address for matching records between systems.  Result is duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

### I have filed a bug report for this

> #### https://issuetracker.google.com/188860467

Be sure to go and star it to show Google that you are affected by this which also subscribes you to updates.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - it is now 2 years later and I still see this issue and that in the issue tracker status it says intended behavior - won't fix.

I was having the exact same problem except that sometimes even multiple queries (including warm-up the cache queries) still did not always get a result.

My script was processing a spreadsheet rows sequentially in date/time order and adding/updating/removing contacts as needed. And the newly added contact did not show up in searchContacts() results to be updated or deleted.

Finally, I had to resort to pre-processing the entire spreadsheet to create a single, finalized operation per contact and only then do the People API work.

This seems really strange to me.